How can I preserve specific built-in types for System.Text.Json AOT?
I have a object structure like List<Dictionary<string, int>> and I serialize it directly with JsonSerializer. Obviously I can't use it as it is for AOT or I get:
JSON serialization and deserialization might require types that cannot be statically analyzed. Use the overload that takes a JsonTypeInfo or JsonSerializerContext, or make sure all of the required types are preserved.
Now I know how it is typically done when using your own custom types, but what are my options for built-in?

str is not a built-in type, string is. Are you sure you shouldn't be using List<Dictionary<string, int>>?

Have you considered Data Contract and System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer instead? I don't like this particular serializer, but at least it handles data contracts correctly with all the required .NET API classes (collections and so on).

By "preserve" you mean "serialize and deserialize", right?

You set up JSON source generation for system types TSystem in exactly the same way you do for custom types: define some JsonSerializerContext with [JsonSerializable(typeof(TSystem))] applied:
[JsonSourceGenerationOptions(WriteIndented = true)] // Add whatever options you want here.
[JsonSerializable(typeof(List<Dictionary<string, int>>))]
// Add additional [JsonSerializable(typeof(T))] attributes as required.
public partial class MySerializationContext : JsonSerializerContext;

The only question is, what JsonTypeInfo<TSystem> property name will be generated for MySerializationContext for a generic system type like List<Dictionary<string, int>>?  As it turns out, it's formed by concatenating all the type names in order, i.e. ListDictionaryStringInt32:
List<Dictionary<string, int>> list = new()
{
    new() { {"foo", 10}, {"bar", 20}, }
};

var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(
    list, 
    MySerializationContext.Default.ListDictionaryStringInt32);

If you're not sure, you can instead call JsonSerializerContext.GetTypeInfo(Type) to get the required type info in runtime:
var typeInfo = (JsonTypeInfo<List<Dictionary<string, int>>>?)MySerializationContext.Default.GetTypeInfo(list.GetType());
if (typeInfo == null)
    throw new JsonException($"TypeInfo not found for {list.GetType()}");
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(list, typeInfo);

You can also determine the property name by using reflection in the debugger:
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", MySerializationContext.Default.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name)));

